# How do I defend against Request Header Alteration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I am not sure of what it is called, but what happens is that my POST method request can be captured by a tool like (burp suite) and change the POST to GET.

Afterwards the process would still continue, but now it shows the parameters and its value in the URL.

How do I defend against this kind of attack?

The website is on ASP.NET C#.

Comment: Yes it is an MITM. I am on https. Apologies if the problem is obvious, but I have no idea on what to look for. 

"From a server perspective: you could not allow GET when you're expecting POST." 
- I'll look into this. thanks a lot!

Comment: I've added an answer, and at the bottom I've explained why worrying about GET vs POST here is not a useful thing to be worrying about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Burp suite is a "man in the middle" (MITM) proxy with injection/manipulation capability. If your site is on http (not https), then yes: you are completely at the mercy of every intermediary that the traffic passes through. Change your site **immediately** to use https with a valid certificate.

For this to work on https, you need to **deliberately break your machine**, by [installing a dodgy root certificate authority](https://portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy_options_installingcacert) that will issue fake certificates for the sites it wants to MITM. This only passes your browser's security system **because you broke your machine**.

An attack that depends on the client already having been compromised is not an interesting attack from a *server* perspective. All you can reasonably do is protect *intact* clients. By using https and disabling http (non-TLS). You can do things like reject GET if you're expecting POST - but this doesn't change that the GET will have happened. But note:

- the MITM proxy *can already* read the POST variables without needing to change them to GET: it is in complete control of the data
- other intermediaries between the MITM proxy and your server *cannot* read the data regardless of whether it is GET or POST, as long as it is https (which is why you need to *disable* http, not just enable https)
- the only thing you're changing with GET vs POST here is what appears in your own server logs... and it *doesn't matter* how you respond to the request at that point: it has already been logged, even if you return 404 or 500 or whatever

Comment: This is great knowledge. Thanks a lot! you are right that i have only just enabled https, http binding are still running. I'll have the http removed and retain the https.

Comment: @kberStill note that it may be useful to redirect HTTP clients to HTTPS and enable [Strict Transport Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security).